# Which is an easy to use Document Management System given my requirements

Tags: software-rec, document-management

Original question on SO.

I looked up a lot of threads on a good document management system on SO. So, given all that knowledge, here is my question: What is a very intuitive, open source (preferably with no commercial upgrade) document management system with a good a web interface. Some features that I am looking for :

- Extremely easy to upload documents. Ideally I should have access to a shared folder and should just copy paste the file and it should version it and check changes. Something like what dropbox does.
- Easy to use, search web interface. It would also be nice if I could modify search results to make it display richer information about the documents itself.

I have looked at some platforms like alfresco, Open KM, Jive etc but want a more workable solution. I know Apache solr can be configured to (re)crawl directories and the index can be configured to show richer info. I also just came across Apache JackRabbit that looks very similar. Please tell me if anybody has any experiences with such an implementation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to host this application yourself instead of relying on already available solutions (Dropbox, Live Mesh, etc)?

Comment: Yes. I cannot use public services like dropbox or live mesh and need to custom index the documents and provide a faceted search interface.I dont think I can do all that with the existing services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided on using either Alfresco or Liferay for document management. Check it out if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying in a Windows or Mono environment, consider [dotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/). It is open source, easy to use and extensible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with a linux environment (i.e. Apache and PostgreSQL), then [DocMGR](http://www.docmgr.org/) might just fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Jungle Disk](https://www.jungledisk.com/index.aspx) in combination with Rackspace or Amazon S3? You can pay a bit extra for web interface, however, I'm not sure if its web interface would satisfy all your requirements, and it's not document management solution per se, but uploading and versioning part works very much like Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

Dokuwiki is great. For textfiles. One folder, drag-drop, edit directly or via the wiki.

How rich are the docs?

Comment: The docs by themselves are in various formats. doc, pdf, xls and so on.