# Recommendations for a Document Management system for Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, windows-explorer, document-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is an easy to use Document Management System given my requirements.](https://superuser.com/questions/28879/which-is-an-easy-to-use-document-management-system-given-my-requirements)

What's the best way to manage a large amount of documents (word,ppt,pdf...) when Windows Explorer is not sufficient? Preferably desktop based solution

Comment: Have a look at http://superuser.com/questions/28879/which-is-an-easy-to-use-document-management-system-given-my-requirements

Answer (score 0):

What would you like to see in such a program? Why is windows explorer not sufficient? You've given us quite little information to go on.

Comment: Ought to be a comment on the question.

Comment: Yes you're quite right but when I realized, it was too late already and I thought I'd just let it here.

Answer (score 0):

Ever try Google Desktop? Sometimes that can help you find files a lot quicker. You just have to be able to remember enough to search for the right files afterward.